# How to get only the first x items starting at position y from a list, using CAML query?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, caml-query, caml

In sharepoint 2010 client object model in javascript, I want to create a caml query, that can download items from a list. I have this part working, but I want to download only x items, not the whole thing. Also I want to be able to get the first x items, but starting from position y.

Is this possible to do in CAML query?

**EDIT:**

```
// This part downloads the list information and adds it to the DOM
function getRelventItems(office, cat) {

    // reset ajax checking functions
    window.ajax_calls = 0;
    window.can_reveal_menu = false;

    display_loading(false);

    // remove the markerplace suffix to match the check box names in the edit form
    office = office.replace(" Marketplace","");

    // build the where clause
    var specifier = "";
    if (office == "" && cat == "") {
        specifier = "<Eq><FieldRef Name='" + window.fields[8] + "'/><Value Type='User'><UserID/></Value></Eq>";
    } else if (office == "All Offices" && cat != "All") {
        specifier = "<Eq><FieldRef Name='" + window.fields[3] + "'/><Value Type='MultiChoice'>" + cat + "</Value></Eq>";
    } else if (office != "All Offices" && cat == "All") {
        specifier = "<Eq><FieldRef Name='" + window.fields[2] + "'/><Value Type='MultiChoice'>" + office + "</Value></Eq>";
    } else if (office != "All Offices" && cat != "All") {
        specifier = "<And><Eq><FieldRef Name='" + window.fields[2] + "'/><Value Type='MultiChoice'>" + office + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='" + window.fields[3] + "'/><Value Type='MultiChoice'>" + cat + "</Value></Eq></And>";
    }

    // create a caml query, and make sure the downloaded info is sorted in order of modified data in ascending order
    var camlquerystring = "<View><Query><Where>" + specifier + "</Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>" + window.pagelimit.toString() + "</RowLimit></View>";   

    // get the list
    var list = window.web.get_lists().getByTitle(window.listname);

    // create the caml query
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    query.set_viewXml(camlquerystring);


    var position = new SP.ListItemCollectionPosition();
    position.set_pagingInfo("Paged=TRUE&p_ID=1"); //to get items from the second
    query.set_listItemCollectionPosition(position); 

    // download items from sharepoint list using the caml query
    this.listItems = list.getItems(query);
    window.clientContext.load(listItems, 'Include(' + get_context_string() + ')');

    // set up an on-success function and an on-failure function
    window.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onListItemsLoadSuccess),Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check [this post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14008.custom-or-advance-paging-in-sharepoint-20102013-using-client-object-model-jquery.aspx). The main point is to use "RowLimit" in your query:

```
query = new SP.CamlQuery(); 
query.set_viewXml("<View><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>");
```

And set [listItemCollectionPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557782%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property:

```
var position = new SP.ListItemCollectionPosition();
position.set_pagingInfo("Paged=TRUE&p_ID=1"); //to get items from the second
query.set_listItemCollectionPosition(position);
```

Comment: for the position, is it 0 based index or 1 based index?
like to start from the second item for example, do I give 1 or 2 as the position?

Comment: I tried
 var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
 query.set_viewXml(camlquerystring);
 query.set_listItemCollectionPosition(0); 
but it didn't work, the query came back with a error.
I was trying to get items starting form the first item.

Comment: ListItemCollectionPosition is not a number, it is an object with property PagingInfo that you need to update. I updated my answer with example.

Comment: It didn't work, I am still getting all the items. To give more information, I am getting the list items sorted by modified date desc. And I want the items starting from the second item (after its sorted). So the item ID doesn't count here I believe.

Comment: Could you provide the code that you used?

Comment: ok I added it above.

Comment: "p_ID" is an ID of the list item which will be the first in query results. So, you need to reuse listItemCollectionPosition from the previous query as done in the post that I provided in my answer.

Comment: But how does that work? I am creating like a pagination thing, and what if I click to show items from page 10, how can I retrieve the items that would one would expect to be in page 10 (being that the list needs to be sorted my modified date desc)? I don't understand how listItemCollectionPosition helps, because it only gives you the index of the last item returned. How would I know the item ID to get items for the 10th page?

Comment: That's how SharePoint paging works... To get items from 10th page you need to load 1,2...9 pages before, to get start item ID for the 10th page.

Comment: if thats the case, then I am better off doing a "previous|next" button.